# Change DateTime format and validate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, model-binding

I am migrating the Web API .NET framework 4.7 to .NET 6 Web API and have a hard time setting up DateTime format in Model.

```
public class ExportStatisticParams
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "2015-1-1", "2030-12-31")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "2015-1-1", "2030-12-31")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set up DateTime format to yyyy-MM-dd but when action is submitted and validator kicks in it display validation message like this:

```
"errors": {
    "EndDate": [
      "The field EndDate must be between 1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/2030 12:00:00 AM."
    ],
    "StartDate": [
      "The field StartDate must be between 1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/2030 12:00:00 AM."
    ]
  }
```

Why 1/1/2015 and not 2015-1-1?

In Web API .NET framework 4.7 the default format was yyyy-MM-dd and now it changed to MM/dd/yyyy

---

I just tested again and it seems everything is fine with the Date Time format, the web API accepts date formats like 2015-1-1. The only problem is that the validation message displays the date as 1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM and not 2015-1-1 as set in DataFormatString. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: Tried this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd68c995-5a6a-420e-9c71-6bc5843d332a/cant-use-dataformatstring-to-format-datetime#779361f4-c435-41e6-8539-ae0fe3de22ce-isAnswer

Comment: @naveen not sure to what you want to refer me. Do you mean to set {0:yyyy-MMM-dd} format? That doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed that by adding Date formating in ErrorMessage like this

[Range(typeof(DateTime), "2015-1-1", "2030-12-31", ErrorMessage = "{0} should be between {1:yyyy-MM-dd} and {2:yyyy-MM-dd}.")]